# htaccess for clean URLs without hard coding of get variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, clean-urls

I am trying to rewrite a URL from something like this:

http://www.domain.com/index.php/service/variable1/value/variable2/value      ....all the way to 8 variables.

To this:

http://www.domain.com/index.php?pagekey=service&variable1=value&variable2=value ....all the way to 8 variables.

The variables are going to change from page to page, so I cannot hard code them in the rewrite rule. The variable and the value both need to be htaccess variables.

I have the following htaccess code working perfectly on Apache 2.2.9 (debian), but the same code DOESNT work on apache 2.2.16 (debian) OR apache 2.2.22 (debian)

Anyone have any ideas as to why this may be?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif|php))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ index.php?pagekey=$1
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ index.php?pagekey=$1

RewriteRule ^index/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3

RewriteRule ^index/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5

RewriteRule ^index/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7

RewriteRule ^index/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?pagekey=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7&$8=$9
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do this? The existing var1/var2/var3 syntax is much more human readable / easier for a user to re-type than what you are trying to rewrite it to.

Comment: To be able to access the variables in PHP using $_GET instead of trying to parse out the URL. The user would always see the first URL example I posted, however PHP would see it as the second.

Comment: what messsage or error are you getting? Also you should always get in the habit using the `[L]` at the end of every RewriteRule

Comment: @PanamaJack I am not getting an error message, it just seems to ignore everything after the index.php/ in the URL. The GET variable is empty when I try to access it in PHP ($_GET['pagekey'])

Answer (score 0):

You can handle all these combinations with these 3 **generic rules**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(index)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?pagekey=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(index)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?pagekey=$2&$3=$4 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(index)(?:\.php)?/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ $1.php/$2$5?$3=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried this one too, it behaves the same way as the original one. Could there be something in the apache configuration that I am missing? I have allowed override and have enabled mod-rewrite module. Anything else that could be preventing this from working?

Comment: First this is properly tested generic solution that worked fine on my Apache. Now tell what full URL you tried and what error you got? Make sure when you test this there is no other rule in this .htaccess.